# Delphi TClientdataset vs Marshmallow ORM populated from REST Performance comparison

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, spring4d

I am looking at using a node REST (json) service consumed by a Marshmallow ORM on client side to act as a persistence layer. I was wondering if anyone has experience / views of speed of such a persistence approach compared to straight tclientdataset approach - across CRUD operations. I prefer the ORM approach with objects as I believe it provides way more flexibility on client side rather than referring to cds all over.

Any views much appreciated:)

Comment: I see this being closed because "primarily opinion based" - be welcome to ask this on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spring4d - we currently only support database backends but in general there is no reason not to support other backends

Comment: Thanks will post as you suggested, I posted a question to get a quick overview of what would be required (in the expert's view) to consume a REST endpoint in the Marshmallow ORM framework. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944230/tsession-to-consume-restful-data-service-implementation). Do you mind giving me your views on potential approach?